# already installed but ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I'm pretty sure I have installed scikit learn because I've tried pip install and Conda in terminal and I get the message `"# All requested packages already installed."` but when I run my code in Python 3.7.1 I keep getting the error `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'"`

```
import csv
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dates = []
prices = []

def get_data(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        csvFileReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        next(csvFileReader)
        for row in csvFileReader:
            dates.append(float(row[0].split('-')[0]))
            prices.append(float(row[1]))
    return

def predict_prices(dates, prices, x):
    dates = np.reshape(dates,(len(dates), 1))
    svr_lin = SVR(kernel = 'linear', C = 1e3)
    svr_poly = SVR(kernel = 'poly', C = 1e3, degree = 2)
    svr_rbf = SVR(kernel = 'rbf', C = 1e3, gamma = 0.1)
    svr_lin.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_poly.fit(dates, prices)
    svr_rbf.fit(dates, Prices)

plt.scatter(dates, prices, color = 'black', label = 'Data')
plt.plot(dates, svr_rbf.predict(dates), color = 'red', label = 'RBF model')
plt.plot(dates, svr_lin.predict(dates), color = 'green', label = 'Linear model')
plt.plot(dates, svr_poly.predict(dates), color = 'blue', label = 'Polynomial model')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.title('Price')
plt.title('Support Vector Regression')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

return svr_rbf.predict(x)[0], svr_lin.predict(x)[0], svr_poly.predict(x)[0]

get_data('EURUSD4h.csv')

predictedPrice = predict_prices(dates, prices, 29)
print(predictedPrice)
```

Comment: Try `sudo pip3  install scikit-learn` or `pip3  install scikit-learn`

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.2 in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.15.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.13.3 in ./miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from scikit-learn) (1.1.0)

Comment: which editor you are using?

Comment: just using the python 3.7.1 IDLE

Answer (score -1):

You should use Anaconda instead of Miniconda for getting all the dependencies installed by default in your starting phase . 
Also , if you want to install all dependencies and to be used in all editors , prefer to download the packages from PyPy and goto folder and run the command :

```
python setup.py install
```

Sometimes installing packages through pip don't show up in Jupyter Notebook so I prefer this way .

Also , your code is having errors as svr_rbf and svr_lin would not be accessible in plt.plot .